# Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto

Tags: c#, .net

Criei uma DLL com a opção "Register COM Interop" em C# onde é consumido alguns WebServices de diferentes prefeituras. Utilizo esta DLL em um aplicativo Windows Form C# de teste onde não ocorre nenhum erro.

Ao utilizar a DLL em um aplicativo Delphi me retorna o Erro:

> Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Alguém já passou por isso?

Segue o código abaixo:

```
[ComVisible(true),
Guid("49E06C86-FC1A-418A-A12D-550797702A84"),
ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IAbrasfV201_Events))]
public class SigISS : ISigISS_Interface
{
    public void GeraNF(string AEnderecoWebService, string ACCM, string ACNPJ, string ASenha, string ACRC, string ACRC_UF, 
        string AAliquotaSimples, int ANumeroNotaFiscal, int ADiaEmissao, int AMesEmissao, int AAnoEmissao, string AServico, 
        string ASituacaoNF, double AValor, double ABase, string ADescricaoNF, int ATomadorTipo, string ATomadorCNPJ, 
        string ATomadorEmail, string ATomadorInscrMunicipal, string ATomadorInscrEstadual, string ATomadorRazaoSocial, 
        string ATomadorNomeFantasia, string ATomadorEndereco, string ATomadorNumero, string ATomadorComplemento, 
        string ATomadorBairro, string ATomadorCep, string ATomadorCodCidade, string ATomadorFone, string ATomadorRamal, 
        string ATomadorFax, string ARPSNumero, string ARPSSerie, int ARPSDia, int ARPSMes, int ARPSAno, out int AResultado, 
        out int ANotaGerada, out string ALinkImpressao, out string AAutenticidade, out string AErros)
    {
        AResultado = 0;
        ANotaGerada = 0;
        ALinkImpressao = string.Empty;
        AAutenticidade = string.Empty;
        AErros = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            ClientWBAws.br.com.sigiss.testebauru.tcDescricaoRps DescricaoRps = new br.com.sigiss.testebauru.tcDescricaoRps();
            ClientWBAws.br.com.sigiss.testebauru.tcRetornoNota RetornoNota = new br.com.sigiss.testebauru.tcRetornoNota();
            ClientWBAws.br.com.sigiss.testebauru.tcEstruturaDescricaoErros EstruturaDescricaoErros = new br.com.sigiss.testebauru.tcEstruturaDescricaoErros();
            ClientWBAws.br.com.sigiss.testebauru.tcEstruturaDescricaoErros[] DescricaoErros;
            ClientWBAws.br.com.sigiss.testebauru.WebServiceSigISS wsClient = new br.com.sigiss.testebauru.WebServiceSigISS();
            wsClient.Url = AEnderecoWebService;

            DescricaoRps.ccm = ACCM;
            DescricaoRps.cnpj = ACNPJ;
            DescricaoRps.senha = ASenha;
            if (ACRC.Trim() != "")
                DescricaoRps.crc = ACRC;
            if (ACRC_UF.Trim() != "")
                DescricaoRps.crc_estado = ACRC_UF;
            if (StrToIntDef(AAliquotaSimples, 0) > 0)
                DescricaoRps.aliquota_simples = AAliquotaSimples;
            DescricaoRps.servico = StrToIntDef(AServico, 0);
            DescricaoRps.situacao = ASituacaoNF;
            DescricaoRps.valor = string.Format("{0:N2}", AValor);
            DescricaoRps.@base = string.Format("{0:N2}", ABase);
            DescricaoRps.descricaoNF = ADescricaoNF;
            DescricaoRps.tomador_tipo = ATomadorTipo;
            DescricaoRps.tomador_cnpj = ATomadorCNPJ;
            DescricaoRps.tomador_email = ATomadorEmail;
            DescricaoRps.tomador_ie = ATomadorInscrEstadual;
            DescricaoRps.tomador_im = ATomadorInscrMunicipal;
            DescricaoRps.tomador_razao = ATomadorRazaoSocial;
            DescricaoRps.tomador_fantasia = ATomadorNomeFantasia;
            DescricaoRps.tomador_endereco = ATomadorEndereco;
            DescricaoRps.tomador_numero = ATomadorNumero;
            DescricaoRps.tomador_complemento = ATomadorComplemento;
            DescricaoRps.tomador_bairro = ATomadorBairro;
            DescricaoRps.tomador_CEP = ATomadorCep;
            DescricaoRps.tomador_cod_cidade = ATomadorCodCidade;
            DescricaoRps.tomador_fone = ATomadorFone;
            DescricaoRps.tomador_ramal = ATomadorRamal;
            DescricaoRps.tomador_fax = ATomadorFax;
            DescricaoRps.rps_num = ANumeroNotaFiscal;
            DescricaoRps.rps_serie = ARPSSerie;
            DescricaoRps.rps_dia = ARPSDia;
            DescricaoRps.rps_mes = ARPSMes;
            DescricaoRps.rps_ano = ARPSAno;
            DescricaoRps.dia_emissao = ARPSDia;
            DescricaoRps.mes_emissao = ARPSMes;
            DescricaoRps.ano_emissao = ARPSAno;

            RetornoNota = wsClient.GerarNota(DescricaoRps, out DescricaoErros);
            AResultado = RetornoNota.Resultado;
            ANotaGerada = RetornoNota.Nota;
            ALinkImpressao = RetornoNota.LinkImpressao;
            AAutenticidade = RetornoNota.autenticidade;
            AErros = RetornaErros(DescricaoErros);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            AErros = e.Message;
        }
    }


    private static int StrToIntDef(string valor, int @Default)
    {
        int numero;
        if (int.TryParse(valor, out numero))
            return numero;
        return @Default;
    }

    private string RetornaErros(br.com.sigiss.testebauru.tcEstruturaDescricaoErros[] DescricaoErro)
    {
        string Retorno = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i <= (DescricaoErro.Length -1); i++)
        {
            Retorno = "Identificador SIGISS " + DescricaoErro[i].id.ToString() +"\r\n";
            Retorno += "Processo " + DescricaoErro[i].DescricaoProcesso + "\r\n";
            Retorno += "Erro " + DescricaoErro[i].DescricaoErro + "\r\n";
        }
        return Retorno;
    }
```

Comment: Esse é um erro muito genérico... POde fornecer mais detalhes?

Comment: Ocorre um erro ou essa mensagem de erro é retornada pelo parâmetro AErros? Se for retornada por este parâmetro mude a linha que atribui ela de `AErros = e.Message;` para `AErros = e.ToString();` para pegar mais informações sobre o erro.

Answer (score 1):

Criei uma dll que assina os xml antes de transmitir os lotes de rps para a prefeitura, a empresa utiliza pelo Delphi também, além da opção "Register for COM interop" estar marcada, acessa o arquivo AssemblyInfo.cs e verifica essa linha, tem que deixar como true.

```
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]
```

Detalhe: Esse erro de referência de objeto, ocorre quando está tentando acessar um objeto/propriedade que não existe.